# Features, Drush and Drupal 6

Tags: 6, drush, features

I'm using drush on D6 websites and i would to create and manage my features via drush.So i patched the 1.2 version like in this post :

Then i get an error when i try to create a feature for content types : https://www.drupal.org/node/2283617

```
  $ drush @sitebl fe --d --destination="sites/all/modules/_features"  briselames_content_type  node:page_lycee
....
Unknown option: --destination
```

Have you any idea about this ?

thanks

EDIT1

when i try whithout quotes (or single quotes '') this give an error

```
$ drush @sitebl fe --d -destination=sites/all/modules/_features  briselames_content_type  node:page_lycee
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 3.81 MB]                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.03 sec, 4.01 MB] [bootstrap]
Loaded alias @sitebl from file /home/xxx/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php [0.16 sec, 4.02 MB]                                             [notice]
Cache SET cid: 6.6-dev-alias-path--e9a42ca79125c2d266c093da6a27d238 [0.25 sec, 4.02 MB]                                                             [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 6.6-dev-commandfiles-0-29f4f0296708390047a2c57582fb56a8 [0.27 sec, 4.03 MB]                                                          [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [1.9 sec, 9.59 MB]                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 5. [1.94 sec, 9.59 MB]                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
The drush command 'fe briselames_content_type node:page_lycee' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache[error]
if you have installed new extensions. [1.94 sec, 9.59 MB]
The directory 1 does not contain a valid Drupal installation [1.94 sec, 9.59 MB]                                                                [error]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the destination part of your drush command without the quotes, like so:

> --destination=sites/all/modules/_features

Curious to see if this helps ...

**Updated answer**, now related to the new error after "edit1" in the question: Try running the comment again, but now with this slightly corrected command (note the "--destination" instead of "-destination"), like so:

> $ drush @sitebl fe --d --destination=sites/all/modules/_features  briselames_content_type  node:page_lycee